# class in OOP language and type

Tags: object-oriented, programming-languages, class, type-systems

In programming language theory, a type is a set of values. E.g. the type "int" is the set of all integer values.

In OOP languages, a class is a type, is it?

When a class is defined with more than one members, e.g.

```
class myclass{
    int a; 
    double b;
}
```

When we talk about a class, do we mean

- "`(a,b)` where `a` is an int and `b` is a double", or
- "{`(x,y)` | `x` is any int, `y` is any double}"?

What does an instance of `myclass` mean?

- "`(a,b)` where `a` is an int and `b` is a double", or
- an object which occupies a memory space and which can (not necessarily, i.e. can be empty) store `(x,y)`, where `x` is any int and `y` is any double?

Comment: A class is a type. *"{(x,y) | x is any int, y is any double}""* would be almost correct, except for two things: 1) you've used a tuple while a class is conceptually a record - you refer to its fields by name, not position; and 2) Not every record with fields `a` and `b` are members of that type, as Killian Forth mentions. Myclass is *isomorphic* to records with fields `a` and `b` of type `int` and `double` - you could take a record like that and turn it into an instance of `myclass`.

Comment: In strongly-typed languages, a class is a type. In weakly-typed languages, it may or may not be a type.

Comment: why "In strongly-typed languages, a class is a type. In weakly-typed languages, it may or may not be a type." @shawnhcorey

Comment: In programming language theory, a type is a set of values? I think you need to get yourself an other book or other teacher or both. A 'variable' or a 'constant' has a 'type' and often has a 'value'. There are zero value types, scalars and composit value types where the value of the variable or constant contains sub-variables/sub-constants.

Comment: @user1703394 A type *is* a set of values. A 32-bit integer type is a set of 2^32 distinct values. If an expression evaluates to a value of that type, you know that value is in that set. The  mathematical operators are just functions over values of that set.

Comment: I would also be cautious considering types as sets of values. Sets have relations that are not strictly applicable to types. For conceptualizing types it's a good model, but it breaks down once you start looking at things more closely - and even moreso when you introduce subtyping.

Comment: @Telastyn Subtyping does complicate the picture because then you also have to take semantics into account (e.g. natural numbers aren't a subtype of integers because you can always subtract two integers, yet you can't always subtract two naturals). But I'm not aware of any relation that holds for sets that doesn't hold for types.

Comment: @Doval - the simple one, akin to the top answer: if you have two sets that contain the same values, they are equivalent mathematically. Types are (usually) not.

Comment: @Telastyn There's still no problem, because different types don't share values. A `box` with a single `int` field is not an `int`; therefore the set of all `box`es is distinct from the set of all `ints`. This is the same reason why you can't mix units in physics. We just establish a one-to-one correspondence between distances and reals so that if we convert two meters into two reals and add the reals, we can get the corresponding sum of the two distances. See [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/98241/what-justifies-dimensional-analysis) for a more thorough explanation.

Comment: @Doval - that's a good point. I overlooked it since I've been neck deep in a language where individual values can exist in multiple types.

Comment: @Telastyn Actually, I should've phrased that a bit differently. Different types *can* share values, since a union of two types contains all the members of both types. But the union is still a distinct set since it has members that don't belong to one or the other type.

Comment: In many programming languages, including Java and C#, there is no way to declare a storage location which can hold a class object; instead, class object instances are "free-standing" objects which cannot be held directly in storage locations but can only be *identified* by *references* stored in those locations.  Given `SomeClassType foo;`, the statement `foo=bar;` will change `foo` so that it identifies the same object as `bar`, but won't affect the object itself; `foo.someField=12;` will alter the object *identified by* `foo`, but won't affect `foo` itself.

Comment: The way such languages handle references means that an object of a derived type is an object of its base type, but a storage location of a derived type is not a storage location of the base type.  Thus, the question of whether a `DerivedType` is a `BaseType` depends upon the context in which the types are used.

Comment: Just a really pendantic note, in PL theory we usually wouldn't state that a type is a set of its values because this doesn't actually work when you add functions + generics. With even fancier type systems you can run into Russell's paradox as well.

Comment: A type is more than just a range of possible values, types also have defined purpose and behavior.

Comment: Also you rather miss the point that a class is not only a collection of data, but, also contains all the methods and functions that operate on that data. The tight linking of data and the code that manipulates it is a the core of OO.

Comment: @Mr.Mindor *"Types also have defined purpose and behavior"* You're describing an *abstract* data type.

Comment: @Doval,that is wrong in so many ways.A 32-bit integer type is just that, a 32-bit integer type. A variable of that type has a value.The specific value of the variable can be seen to be part of the set that includes 2^32 distinct possible values of the exact same type.The 'type' however should never be equated to the 'set'!Sets can be operated on only for types that are related in specific ways.Seriously,a book or teacher that conflates types with sets is bad in so many ways that I truly hope non actually exist.But given that both you and Gnat believe this to be true makes me fear the worst.

Comment: @user1703394 You know you just agreed with me when you said "the specific value of the variable can be seen to be part of the set that includes...", right? This isn't something I made up or anything - see [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9190352/abusing-the-algebra-of-algebraic-data-types-why-does-this-work) and [this article](http://chris-taylor.github.io/blog/2013/02/10/the-algebra-of-algebraic-data-types/). See especially part 3, where they show how the "zipper" for any algebraic data type happens to be the derivative of that type.

Comment: @Doval, I would suggest trying to put the relationships between variables, values, types and sets into two diagrams.One for your nonsensical statement that 'A 32-bit integer type is a set of 2^32 distinct values', and one for mine stating that 'A 32-bit integer type; A variable of that type has a value;The specific value of the variable can be seen to be part of the set that includes 2^32 distinct possible values of the exact same type'. A type is NOT a set! Types and sets are completely different beasts.

Answer (score 30):

Neither.

I take it you're asking whether having the same set of field types is enough to classify as being the same class, or whether they have to be named identically as well. The answer is: "Not even having the same types **and** the same names is sufficient!" *Structurally* equivalent classes are not necessarily type-compatible.

For instance, if you have a `CartesianCoordinates` and a `PolarCordinates` class, they might both have two numbers as their fields, and they might even have the same `Number` type and the same names, but they would still not be compatible, and an instance of `PolarCoordinates` would not be an instance of `CartesianCoordinates`. The ability to separate types by their intended *purpose* and not their current *implementation* is a very useful part of writing safer, more maintainable code.

Comment: It should be noted that in some languages being structurally equivalent _is_ enough to make one type a subtype of the other (and often vice versa). That though is decidedly uncommon/unpopular.

Comment: (1) given your examples, in programming language theory, is a type not just a set of values? how shall a type be defined? (2) Another example, if in C, "typedef" an existing type to be a new type, will the new and the original types be the same or different?

Comment: @Tim A typedef doesn't create a type, it aliases the name used to refer to an existing type.

Comment: @Doval: That depends on the language, doesn't it?

Comment: @DevSolar He explicitly mentioned C, and other than C++, I don't know of any other language that uses that keyword.

Comment: @Telastyn - those languages should be killed with fire.

Comment: @JonStory Structural subtyping is useful at a module level; the lack of it is what forces you to turn everything into an `interface` in Java and C# if you ever want to do unit testing. You end up writing a ton of boilerplate just so you can change the particular class your program will use even though you don't have any intention of changing it at runtime.

Comment: @JonStory: Adding on to what Doval said, sometimes whoever wrote the original class didn't think ahead and use an `interface` in the first place.  Then writing a polymorphic replacement gets a lot harder.

Comment: @Kevin And sometimes an `interface` isn't a good solution even if you could add one. If you define your own numeric type, you can't do anything useful without looking at two instances of it, but if you have two `INumber`s there's no guarantee they have the same type. Likewise, if you want to *efficiently* merge two heaps, you're going to have to look at the private data of both of them. In general, an `interface` doesn't work well whenever binary methods are involved, unless you cheat with `instanceof` and either blow up or fall back to something slow when the types don't match.

Answer (score 6):

Types are not sets.

You see, set theory has a number of features which simply *don't apply* to types, and *vice-versa*.  For instance, an object has a single canonical type.  It may be an instance of several different types, but only one of those types was used to instantiate it.  Set theory has no notion of "canonical" sets.

Set theory allows you to [create subsets on the fly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_separation), if you have a rule that describes what belongs to the subset.  Type theory generally does not allow this.  While most languages have a `Number` type or something similar, they *do not* have an `EvenNumber` type, nor would it be straightforward to create one.  I mean, it's easy enough to define the type itself, but any existing `Number`s which happen to be even will not be magically transformed into `EvenNumber`s.

Actually, saying that you can "create" subsets is somewhat disingenuous, because sets are a different kind of animal altogether.  In set theory, those subsets *already exist*, in all the infinite ways you can define them.  In type theory, we usually expect to be dealing with a finite (if large) number of types at any given time.  The only types which are said to exist are those we've actually defined, not every type we could possibly define.

Sets are [not allowed to directly or indirectly contain themselves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity).  Some languages, such as Python, provide types with less regular structures (in Python, `type`'s canonical type is `type`, and `object` is considered an instance of `object`).  On the other hand, most languages do not allow *user-defined* types to engage in this sort of trickery.

Sets are commonly allowed to overlap without being contained in one another.  This is uncommon in type theory, though some languages do support it in the form of multiple inheritance.  Other languages, such as Java, only allow a restricted form of this or disallow it entirely.

The empty type exists (it's called the [bottom type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottom_type)), but most languages do not support it, or do not regard it as a first-class type.  The "type that contains all other types" also exists (it's called the [top type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_type)) and is widely supported, unlike set theory.

**NB**: As some commenters previously pointed out (before the thread was moved to chat), it is possible to model types with set theory and other standard mathematical constructs.  For instance, you could model type membership as a relation rather than modeling types as sets.  But in practice, this is much simpler if you use [category theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_theory) instead of set theory.  This is how Haskell models its type theory, for example.

---

The notion of "subtyping" is really quite different from the notion of "subset."  If `X` is a subtype of `Y`, it means we can [substitute](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) instances of `Y` for instances of `X` and the program will still "work" in some sense.  This is behavioral rather than structural, though some languages (e.g. Go, Rust, arguably C) have chosen the latter for reasons of convenience, either to the programmer or the language implementation.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20527/discussion-on-answer-by-kevin-class-in-oop-language-and-type).

Answer (score 4):

[Algebraic data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type) are the way to discuss this.

There are three fundamental ways you can combine types:

- Product. That's basically what you're thinking of:

  ```
  struct IntXDouble{
    int a; 
    double b;
  }
  ```

  is a product type; its values are all possible combinations (i.e. tuples) of one `int` and one `double`. If you consider the number types as sets, then the cardinality of the product type is in fact the product of the fields' cardinalities.
- Sum. In procedural languages this is a bit awkward to express directly (classically it's done with *tagged unions*), so for better understanding, here is a sum type in Haskell:

  ```
  data IntOrDouble = AnInt Int
                   | ADouble Double
  ```

  the values of this type have either the form `AnInt 345`, or `ADouble 4.23`, but there's always only one number involved (unlike for the product type, where each value has two numbers). So the cardinality: you first enumerate all `Int` values, each must be combined with the `AnInt` constructor. *Plus*, all `Double` values, each combined with `ADouble`. Hence *sum type*.
- Exponentiation<sup>1</sup>. I'll not discuss that in detail here because it has no clear OO correspondence at all.

So what about classes? I deliberately used the keyword `struct` rather than `class` for `IntXDouble`. The thing is, a class as a type isn't really characterised by its fields, those are merely implementation details. The crucial factor is rather, what *distinguishable* values can the class have.

What *is* relevant though is, a class's value can be *values of **any** of it's subclasses*! So a class is actually a sum type rather than a product type: if `A` and `B` would both be derived from `myClass`, the `myClass` would essentially be the sum of `A` and `B`. Regardless of actual implementation.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>This is functions (in the [mathematical sense!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_%28mathematics%29)); a function type `Int -> Double` is represented by the exponential `Double`<sup>`Int`</sup>. To bad if your language doesn't have proper functions...</sub>

Comment: Sorry, but I think this is a very poor answer. Functions *do* have a clear OO analogue, namely *methods* (and single-method interface types). The basic definition of an object is that it has both *state* (fields/data members) and *behavior* (methods/member functions); your answer ignores the latter.

Comment: @ruakh: no. You can of course implement functions in OO, but in general, methods are not functions (_because_ they modify state etc.). Nor are "functions" in procedural languages functions, for that matter. Indeed, single-static-method interfaces come closest to function/exponential-types, but I hoped to avoid the discussion of that because it has no relevance for this question.

Comment: ...more importantly, my anwer _does_ consider behaviour. Indeed behaviour is usually the reason why you use inheritance, and the unification of different possible behaviours precisely captures the sum-type aspect of OO classes.

Comment: @ruakh A method can't without its object. The closest analog is `static` methods, except they're still not first-class values. The thing about most OO languages is that they take objects as the smallest building block, so if you want anything *smaller* you have to fake it with objects, and you still end up dragging in a bunch of semantics functions shouldn't have. E.g. it doesn't make sense to compare functions for equality, but you can still compare two faux-function objects.

Comment: @Doval 1) you can pass methods around AFAIK, so they are first-class values; 2) it does make sense to compare functions for equality, JS people do it all the time.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry but I don't know about the "raw" theory. I can only provide a practical approach. I hope this is acceptable at programmers.SE; I'm not familiar with the etiquette here.

---

A central theme of OOP is *information hiding*. What the data members of a class are, exactly, should be of no interest to its clients. A client sends *messages* to (calls methods / member functions of) an instance, which might or might not modify internal state. The idea is that the internals of a class might change, without the client being affected by it.

A corrolary to this is that the *class* is responsible for ensuring that its internal representation remains "valid". Let's assume a class that stores a (simplified) phone number in two integers:

```
    int areacode;
    int number;
```

These are the *data members* of the class. However, the class will probably be *much more* than just its data members, and it is certainly not definable as "set of all possible values of int x int". You shouldn't have direct access to the data members.

Construction of an instance might deny any negative numbers. Perhaps the construction would also normalize the areacode in some way, or even verify the whole number. You would thus end up much closer to your `"(a,b) where a is an int and b is a double"`, because it's certainly not *any* two int stored in that class.

But that doesn't really matter as far as the class is concerned. **It is neither the type of the data members, nor the range of their possible values that *defines* the class, it's the *methods* that are defined for it.**

As long as those methods remain the same, the implementor could change the data types to floating point, BIGNUMs, strings, whatever, and for all practical purposes, *it would still be the same class*.

---

There are design patters to ensure that such changes of internal representation can be made without the client even being aware of it (e.g. the pimpl idiom in C++, which hides any data members behind an [opaque pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer#C.2B.2B)).

Comment: `It is neither the type of the data members, nor the range of their possible values that defines the class, it's the methods that are defined for it.` The data members don't define a class only when you hide them. That may be the most common case, but it certainly can't be said that it's true of all classes. If even a single field is public it's just as important as its methods.

Comment: @Doval: If even a single field is public, I pick up my cluebat and seek out the programmer who did that, because that's either a data structure (i.e. not a "class" at all) or broken OOP. ;-)

Comment: Unless you're coding in Java, where you have no choice in the matter and even your dumb no-behavior faux-records must be `class`es. (Marking them `final` helps get the point across, but still). You still have a problem with `protected` members though, which can be inherited and thus form part of a second API for implementors of subclasses.

Comment: @Doval: I understood this to be a "theory" question, which is why I stayed as clear of actual language issues as possible. (Just like I stay as clear of Java and `protected` as possible in practice. ;-) )

Comment: The problem is that a `class` is a language-dependent construct. As far as I know there's no such thing as a `class` in type theory.

Comment: @Doval: Wouldn't that mean that type theory *per se* doesn't apply to classes, as they are a construct out of that theory's scope?

Answer (score 2):

- A *type* is a description of a category/range of values, compound structures, or what have you.  OOPwise, it is akin to an "interface".  (In the language-agnostic sense.  The language-specific sense, not so much.  In Java, for example, `int` is a *type*, but has no relation to an `interface`.  Public/protected field specifications, as well, are not part of an `interface`, but *are* part of an "interface" or *type*.)

  Main point being, it's much more a semantic definition than a concrete one.  Structure only factors in inasmuch as the exposed fields/behaviors *and their defined purposes* align.  If you don't have both, you don't have type compatibility.
- A *class* is the realization of a type.  It's a template that actually defines the internal structure, attached behavior, etc.